# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 in Textbox

Tags: c#

I am getting error on this `int b = Convert.ToInt32(qty.Text);` if i type more than 11 numbers in quantity textbox

```
if (Item_Name.Text == dr["Item_Name"].ToString() && Item_Code.Text == dr["Item_Code"].ToString())
                {
                    int a = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Selling_Price"].ToString());
                    if (qty.Text == "")
                    {
                        Selling_Price.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int b = Convert.ToInt32(qty.Text); //Error On This Line
                        int c = a * b;
                        Selling_Price.Text = c.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Grant Even, 10 numbers can have this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting that exception because an [integer cannot store a number that large](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Int32.MaxValue Field : The value of this constant is 2147483647

Switching to a `long` should solve the problem for you. When you're dealing with numbers that represent money, you might want to consider using `decimal` too.

```
if (Item_Name.Text == dr["Item_Name"].ToString() && Item_Code.Text == dr["Item_Code"].ToString())
{
    int price = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Selling_Price"].ToString());
    if (qty.Text == "")
    {
        Selling_Price.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        long quantity = Convert.ToInt64(qty.Text);
        long total = price * quantity;
        Selling_Price.Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can answer me this question as well i will be thankful to you:

Comment: I am using c# Windows Form.

I have a quantity textbox if i type more then available stock for an selected item so how can i show messagebox and i want textbox.maxlength should be equal to available stock.

Thanks