# Unhandled exception System.OverflowException Value is either too large or too small for Int32

Tags: c#

I have this `C#` code here, and what I'm trying to do is that when I put a number with many digits the application crashes and I want it to not crash but I don't know what to do, I tried changing the `.Parse` command but Idk which command to use instead. An example is that when I run the application I want to put a number like `564984894897987878` and I want the application to not crash, can someone help me, in this case, please? If you find a solution post it here including your code and my code too please and thank you?!

```
        int num;
        Console.Write("Please type your number here:");
        num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        if (num < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("This is a negative number!");

        if (num > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("This number is a positive number");
```

Comment: That number is too large to fit in an `int`, use `long` instead.

Comment: @DavidG I just typed that number instinctlly it was just an example I'm saying with a a number with more than 10 digits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 in Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999963/value-was-either-too-large-or-too-small-for-an-int32-in-textbox)

Comment: An `int` can only be up to `2147483647` whereas `long` will get you to 
`9223372036854775807`. If you want bigger than that then look into `BigInteger`.

Comment: .NET has a `BigInteger` type that supports unlimited precision (well, as long as memory lasts anyway). `System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("564984894897987878")` works, as does `System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890")`. Of course, efficiency in calculating is much lower than with `int`, so it really depends what you want this number for -- if all you need is a `string` and you want to verify it contains only digits, use something else (like `"1234".All(Char.IsDigit)`). If all you want to test is the sign, the first character suffices!

Comment: @Sinatr could you test that code with my code and see if it works and then send it as a solution

Comment: @1Skillz: Is there anything stopping *you* from testing that? If someone has suggested a way forward via another answer, it's then time for *you* to put the effort into understanding and then adapting it for your situation. Stack Overflow is not about being spoon-fed code.

Comment: @1Skillz, it was a first google result for an error that could *possibly* help you. You can use `try/catch` to prevent crashing or use validation to validate user input. It depends on requirement, if requirement is to use `int`, then `int.TryParse` will help. .

Comment: Separately, I would suggest declaring variables at the point of initialization, and using braces on *all* if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TryParse:

```
    Console.Write("Please type your number here:");
    if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");

    if (num < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("This is a negative number!");

    if (num > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("This number is a positive number");
```

Comment: That will stop it from crashing, but I don't think it's what the OP actually wants to do. I believe they want to be able to *handle* large integers, not just "not crash".

Comment: @JonSkeet you may be correct, in that case your solution is the correct one. But in any case parsing a string to any other value I would recomend the TryParse

Comment: Yes, using TryParse is a generally good idea, and I've added it to my answer. I do feel this question is primarily about handling larger integers rather than handling invalid input though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to represent an arbitrarily large integer, you should use [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger).

If you use `int` (aka `System.Int32`) you'll be limited to a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647 inclusive.

If you use `long` (aka `System.Int64`) you'll be limited to a range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 inclusive.

Now it *could* be that `long` is fine for you here - but a user would still be able to crash your app, or at least make it not work "as expected", pretty easily. With `BigInteger` you should be fine for any integer value that your computer has enough memory to store.

Your code can be converted almost trivially to use `BigInteger` - just use `BigInteger.Parse` instead of `Int32.Parse`, and then compare with `BigInteger.Zero`. To improve the code further, beyond just handling large integers, you could use `BigInteger.TryParse` to handle invalid inputs by gracefully reporting those to the user instead of crashing with a `FormatException`.